# Get messages from Gmail via HTTPS GET call

Tags: swift, https, gmail-api

I'm working on an iOS application and what I'd like to do is have the app ping one universal Gmail account to check for the most recent email.

I went through the guide from Google at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift, but the result did not work. After some googling, it appears that some functionality may have been changed, but they haven't updated their documentation yet.

Is there a way to send credentials via https to Gmail and get email messages back? I have an OAuth key via the Gmail API manager, but when I pass it as "access_token", the response says "Login Required".

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, an error response "Login Required" can be encountered if you try to list the buckets for a project that do not provide an authorization header.

If we check [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get), it's noted that it requires [authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#auth).

For this, you may want to check [Authorizing Your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) wherein you will find these basic authorization pattern:

> 1. During development, register the application in the Google API Console.
> 2. When the app launches, request that the user grant access to data in their Google account.
> 3. If the user consents, your application requests and receives credentials to access the Gmail API.
> 4. Refresh the credentials (if necessary).

Furthermore, if your application needs to access Google APIs on behalf of the user, you should use server-side flow. Please see [Implementing Server-Side Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server) for more information.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't need the user's google information. I want to have all users of the app pull the most recent email from the same gmail account behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back I was involved in writing a sample application to access email from gmail but using C++ on windows. The code is at https://github.com/Panchatcharam/simple_gmail_api. I was able to successfully get emails.

Comment: I'm sorry, there's a lot of code there. Could you point me to the specifically relevant portion(s) of code?

Comment: @Ryan, Please take a look at https://github.com/Panchatcharam/simple_gmail_api/blob/master/gmail_access/email_access/email_access/email_access.cpp. I've implemented this using the google gmail api.